# What is an idiomatic Scala way to join strings and remove a specific duplicate element keeping first

Tags: string, scala

I have some strings that have a specific duplicate word between them. I neet to join all these strings keeping the first "duplicated" word and remove the others.

Ex:

```scala
val p1 = "Hello John Doe"
val p2 = "Hello Jane Doe"
val p3 = "Hello Mary"
```

For the output, I'd pass the string to be removed, in this case "Hello" and would like to get a string (or a seq that I can later transform with `mkString(" ")`) with the contents `Hello John Doe Jane Doe Mary`.

The tricky part is that `.distinct` can't be used because it would remove the second "Doe" and it's not desired.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `Doe` (from `Jane Doe`) also be removed?

Comment: Nope, that's the point and tricky part... i could join them all together and use `.distinct` but it would remove the second "Doe" that is not desired.

Comment: Then how to distinguish tokens which should be removed or not? Do you need to filter only first duplicate word?

Comment: I'd pass a word to the function, in this case "Hello".

Comment: Is the word to remove always the first one of each string or could they be in any part? Also, can you have `List[Srtring]` where each string is a word as your inputs instead of plain strings?

Answer (score 3):

Just scan the words, counting occurrences. Boring.

```
@tailrec
def keepN(words: List[String], toDedup: String, toKeep: Int = 1, acc: List[String] = Nil) = words match {
   case Nil => acc.reverse
   case `toDedup` :: tail if toKeep > 0 => keepN(tail, toDedup, toKeep - 1, toDedup::acc)
   case `toDedup` :: tail => keepN(tail, toDedup, 0, acc)
   case head :: tail => keepN(tail, toDedup, toKeep, head :: acc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention a "duplicate word BETWEEN them" which implies that the duplicate is always the first word of each String. So why not just dropping the first few characters?

```
val pList = p1 +: List(p2, p3).map(_.drop(5).trim)
```

Or if you want to refer a specific word...

```
val myWord = "Hello"
val pList = p1 +: List(p2, p3).map(_.drop(myWord.length).trim)
```